# How can i extract the X resolution integer value for X_res column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQFgS.png)

its a machine learning project, i am trying to fetch and save the X_res column as the last integer value of that column.

for example:
for first column of X_res should replace with 2560
for second column of X_res should replace with 1440

Comment: `pd.to_numeric(df['X_res'].str.extract('(\d+)$', expand=False), errors='coerce')`